# parser for information extraction from Web in Python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

My task is to parse an HTML page (in cyrillic) and to extract certain words. Here's a web page I have to parse: http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/. I only got the page:

```
import urllib
from lxml.html import fromstring
url = 'http://www.toponymic-dictionary.in.ua/'
content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
doc = fromstring(content)
doc.make_links_absolute(url)
```

The HTML code is quite complicated for me (to use xpath), so I don't know how to proceed into parsing.

Comment: You *already* parsed the page. `doc` is now a parsed document tree. Try and find some `ElementTree` and / or lxml tutorials, then come back here if you are still stuck on something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look this library: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

And its [Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

It fits best for your requirement.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for help. But as i know BeautifulSoup isn't working with Slavonic languages (e.g. Ukrainian).